# ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0 when attempting to multiply matrix by vector

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have a design matrix X with r rows and c columns, and I want to add a new row that all of its entries are 1 (intercept row) for a learning model.

```
def fit_linear_regression(X, y):
  ones = np.ones(X.shape[1])
  K = np.insert(X.T, 0, ones, axis=1)
  K = K.T
  singulars = np.linalg.svd(K, compute_uv=False)
  w = np.linalg.pinv(K.transpose()) @ y
  return singulars, w
```

The problem is that when I add the desired row outside of the fit_linear_regression function, i.e. when I preprocess the data and then send the matrix as an argument after appending the row of 1s, everything works perfectly fine, but when I attempt to append the row from within the function, I seem to run in to the following issue:

> ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with >gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 18 is different from 17)

I can't seem to pinpoint where the problem is... y is the response vector of 162 rows, and X.T is the transpose of a 162x18 (previously 17), so when I am attempting to multiply them it should work fine.

Updated:
These are the shapes of X and y immediately upon entry to the function:

```
X.shape[0] = 17, X.shape[1] = 162

y.shape[1] = 162
```

Adding the intercept row should change X.shape[0] to 18, and it does, but then this error occurs.
I could add the actual data of X and y, but I find it confusing and unhelpful...

Comment: I think I know what is going on from your update. Try with `fit_linear_regression(X,y.squeeze())`

Comment: Basically the first axis of `y` has to be aligned to with second of `X` but its not. Instead `y.shape[1] = 162` the second is.

Comment: Did it solve it for you?